# CSS: How to put a checkmark icon/acsii character next to all visited links?

Tags: html, css

For any visited (`a:visited`) web page, I would like to display those links on my website with a small checkmark to the left of the link.

So for example:

"this is an unvisited link"

√ "this is a visited link"

**Question**: how do I accomplish the checkmark using CSS?

Comment: Use the :before psuedo-selector for modern browsers, Javascript for crappy browsers and background-images for people who shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a combination of background and padding to get this effect.

```
a:visited {
    background: transparent url("path/to/checkmark.png") left center no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Adjust the padding, and background position to fit your needs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
a:visited:before {
    content: "\00A0\221A";
}
```

[source](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200509/check_marking_visited_links/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:before` pseudo selector, but it's not well supported.

For better support, make it an image, and set it to `background-image`. Then use `padding` to show the image.

Comment: ::before and ::after pseudoelements are well supported in modern browsers, but not supported at all in IE 6 and before. Sometimes that doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeh. Pretty sure it's not supported in IE7 too http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html

Comment: If IE 8 is coming through WU to XP, almost anybody who got IE 7 pushed to them already got IE 8. (Of course, institutional are the wild card.)